# MongoDB: Perform mapreduce and filter with java driver 3.0.x

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, driver

I'm working in a java small project and mongoDB with java driver 3.0.1. Need perform a MapReduce algorithm and before map function, execute one query to have less data and increment the performance.

I've seen api driver and exist the class MongoCollection with method [mapReduce](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#mapReduce-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)  but only with map and reduce function as parameter. it doesn't have any query param.

```
dbConnection.getCollection("test").mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction)
```

In old API, has MapReduceCommand for do this

```
MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand("test", map, reduce, null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, query)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [mapReduce](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#mapReduce-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method on MongoCollection returns an instance of a [MapReduceIterable](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MapReduceIterable.html), which has a [filter](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MapReduceIterable.html#filter-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) method for the query filter to apply to the collection before executing the map phase.  It looks like this:

```
dbConnection.getCollection("test").mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction)
                                  .filter(queryFilter)
```